# TypeScript deserialization is not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I built a model-class to represent an object. Function deserialize should fill it up from a JSON string.

```
export class MyData
{
    public name:string;
    public job:string;

    public deserialize (input:any) : MyData
    {
      Object.assign (this, input);
      return this;
  }    
}
```

---

```
var md:MyData = new MyData ().deserialize ({ name: "max", job: "sales" }));
console.log ("md="+md);
```

But md is still an Object.

```
md=[object Object]
```

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: Ran the code, ms is an instance of `MyClass`, try `console.log ("md="+(md instanceof MyData));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working as expected. `Object.toString()` will return `[object Object]`.

Try `console.log(md.name)`. If you want the whole object as a string, try `JSON.stringify(md)`.

Comment: I missed the fact that toString is not part of MyData. So it is clear that without having toString in MyData the output of "Object" is correct. And it is also clear that my deserialize is working fine - thanks!

Comment: To be clear: `.toString()` *is* part of `MyData`. It's part of the Object prototype. Every data value type in Typescript (Javascript) has a `.toString()` method on it. When you coerce types to strings by adding them to a string (`'m' + myData)`, it's the same as calling `.toString()` on it.